# HTML/javascript vertically expand textbox when text is too long

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I wish the containing element (either a  or  element) to automatically expand vertically to accommodate text that has reach the end of line. Is there a way to do this with plain HTML elements? If not, can I do this using javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: is this taking input from user or you are outputting data from the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autosizing textarea using prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea-using-prototype)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea-using-prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no way to this in plain HTML. With Javascript it's possible though.

Take a look at [jQuery plugin: autoResize](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/). **Note:** this is a plugin for jQuery.

Also, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-textarea) for more jQuery alternatives.