# Wrap text within in a text input

Tags: html

I am needing to wrap text within a text input. I know that textareas have this functionality by default, but I need to use a text input to allow for submit on enter. Pressing enter in a textarea just brings you to a new line.

I've tried word-wrap and word-break, but those don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input Field, wrap text instead of extending horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251661/input-field-wrap-text-instead-of-extending-horizontally)

Comment: @Wowsk that answer uses textarea, question is for text input.

Comment: Yeah all the other questions here accepted answers that tell them to use textareas, but I am looking for an actual solution to this problem. Thank you, though!

Comment: @kiaaanabal its not possible

Comment: But the question is about inputs and the answers tell you that it is not possible

Comment: if you just need submit in textarea you can use onkeyup, - if enter - submit

Comment: @fdfey thank you! We may consider using a textarea and using shift + enter for new line and enter as only submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot wrap an input your best option would be to disable the `enter` in a text area, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/11/

```
<textarea id="something"></textarea>
<script>
$("#something").keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
  }
});
</script>
```